# How to ignore website console error in playwright tests?

Tags: playwright

I'm using playwright for some visual regression testing. On the site in question there third-party scripts that might throw a console error if blocked by the user due to privacy concerns. My playwright tests fail due to those console errors

Is there a way to ignore some or all website console errors so my regression tests pass?

Comment: Are you using jest-playwright? Then you can put `exitOnPageError: false` in your jest-playwright.config.js

Comment: @MaxSchmitt: Thank you. If you can post it as an answer I am happy to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using [jest-playwright](https://github.com/playwright-community/jest-playwright) then you can put `exitOnPageError: false` in your `jest-playwright.config.js`.

See here for more information: https://github.com/playwright-community/jest-playwright#options